# SAS/ACCESS Interface to Teradata QUERY_BAND

Tags: sas, teradata

SAS Libname Statment

```
QUERY_BAND= LIBNAME Option
```

Generate

```
SET QUERY_BAND="BAND;" FOR SESSION;
```

I need to generate this :

```
SET QUERY_BAND='BAND’; FOR SESSION VOLATILE;
```

Whitch statment should I to use?
Statement like `QUERY_BAND_VOLATILE` does not exist.

Comment: Did you try `Proc SQL; Connect using <LIBREF>; EXECUTE (The remote set statement) BY <LIBRREF>`

Answer (score 0):

Your query_band expression is incorrect. Use smth like below, and run it within the Proc SQL as Richard suggested.

SET QUERY_BAND = 'BAND=1;' FOR SESSION VOLATILE;

```
proc sql;

connect to teradata as tdd (server=&SERVER. user=&HCUSER. password=&HCPASS.);

execute(SET QUERY_BAND = 'BAND=1;' FOR SESSION VOLATILE; ) by tdd;

disconnect from tdd;

quit;
```

Comment: I want to use SAS Libname Statment QUERY_BAND it is more correct.